# "A" or "an" with adjective in parenthesis

Tags: indefinite-articles, parentheses

Which of the following two forms is correct? (And if there's no agreement about that, which one is more common?)

> a (optional) parameter
>   an (optional) parameter

The problem is that the choice between "a" and "an" is based on the spoken form of the phrase ("does the next word start with a vowel sound?"), but there is no spoken equivalent to parentheses.

I.e. I can say either:

> a parameter

Or:

> an optional parameter

But I can't pronounce parentheses.

Comment: The correct form is "an (optional) parameter." Otherwise, you are assuming that your reader is going to ignore everything inside the parentheses. That isn't what parentheses are for. If you want to include material that your readers don't have to read, put it in a footnote.

Comment: The question is: How would you speak it aloud? Whether you would pronounce the parenthetical adjective or not will determine what the next word is. And it's ***the next spoken word*** that determines. So say it out loud. That is the rule for _a/an_: Say it out loud.

Comment: You could of course resort to "a(n) (optional) parameter", although I agree that it is not pretty.

Comment: @JohnLawler That's the problem, I don't think I can say it out loud without losing (some of) the meaning.

Comment: I've often used a (n optional) parameter in similar situations.

Comment: Parentheses are inaudible. You can do things in writing you cant do in talking, and vice versa. Mostly vice versa, in fact. But even if you wanna use an effect only available in written language like optional words, you still hafta deal with the effects only available in spoken language, like _a_ versus _an_. You **gotta** say it aloud; if that loses information, too bad. Avoid saying it and avoid using an indefinite article, then; or give up on preserving all the information in every medium. Bandwidth is not infinite.

Comment: Actually, in this particular example, I fail to see how you would lose one bit of meaning. The parentheses really don't add anything at all.

Answer (score -1):

"a parameter (which is optional)"